# Shell Script Assigning json object to an variable for iteration

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, jq

```
DATA="$(curl "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=BA&apikey=demo" | jq '.bestMatches' | jq '.[] | ."1. symbol"')"
```

I want to iterate over DATA variable which would ideally be an array. What I want to do here is two fold.

1. I need a way to select the "1. symbol" attribute of all the records which have a "matchScore" greater than 0.5. This is a problematic thing for me to do since the matchScore contains a string, not a number.
2. I want to store the selected "1. Symbol" attributes in a variable which I can iterate over later to do more operations.

```
{
  "bestMatches": [
    {
      "1. symbol": "BA",
      "2. name": "The Boeing Company",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "1.0000"
    },
    {
      "1. symbol": "BAC",
      "2. name": "Bank of America Corporation",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "0.8000"
    },
    {
      "1. symbol": "BABA",
      "2. name": "Alibaba Group Holding Limited",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "0.6667"
    },
    {
      "1. symbol": "GOLD",
      "2. name": "Barrick Gold Corporation",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "0.5714"
    },
    {
      "1. symbol": "BIDU",
      "2. name": "Baidu Inc.",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "0.5000"
    },
    {
      "1. symbol": "BAYRY",
      "2. name": "Bayer Aktiengesellschaft",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "0.4000"
    },
    {
      "1. symbol": "BLDP",
      "2. name": "Ballard Power Systems Inc.",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "0.3333"
    },
    {
      "1. symbol": "BHC",
      "2. name": "Bausch Health Companies Inc.",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "0.3333"
    },
    {
      "1. symbol": "BK",
      "2. name": "The Bank of New York Mellon Corporation",
      "3. type": "Equity",
      "4. region": "United States",
      "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
      "6. marketClose": "16:00",
      "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
      "8. currency": "USD",
      "9. matchScore": "0.1538"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is the json object I get.

Comment: You need to show a sample of the JSON.

Comment: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=BA&apikey=88JWMNB5WHN15B1J

Comment: from this link you can have a look at the json object : https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=BA&apikey=88JWMNB5WHN15B1J

Comment: All the necessary information should be in the question, not external links.

Comment: You shouldn't post your API key in a public site like this.

Comment: Thank you for the advices. Now I have updated it with the relevant information. and without the API KEY.

Comment: @RathinduWathsala Note that the API key can still be seen in [the older revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65121675/revisions). You should probably revoke it and get a new one.

Comment: The API key is also in your comment, you should delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the field value from integer to number with tonumber and so:

```
readarray data <<< "$(jq -r '.bestMatches[] | select(."9. matchScore" | tonumber > 0.5) | ."1. symbol"' jq)"
```

Redirect the output of the jq command into readarray to create an array.

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem of filterting the things that are only greater than 0.5. what about the assignment of the variable?

Comment: I've amended the answer